# Can't restore my Wii: BootMii Won't Work

Tags: nintendo-wii, homebrew

**I am trying to restore or un-modify my Wii. When I try to start BootMii from the Home Brew Channel, I get only a black screen. Can somebody please help me?**

I don't know how the heck I would have deleted BootMii but maybe that did happen. I do have the NAND.bin and KEYS.bin though. Would I be able to recover a bricked Wii with just these 2 files?

I think I might just need to reinstall BootMii but the official Web site http://bootmii.org/ tells me to install it through HackMii - but I'm afraid to do that since my Wii is *already* hacked.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about console modification.

Comment: Sorry about that @Frank. Where would be the right place to ask questions like these?

Comment: I see that there is a concern about illegal content and I can understand that this community does not want that type of content on this forum. I completely agree and appreciate that. Piracy is absolutely wrong. But this is definitely not piracy. The reason I am trying to get BootMii to work is because I _don't_ want my Wii hacked. I'm trying to _undo_ the modifications and restore it to its original state. If this question is closed, it could make it difficult for me and many other people with the same problem to to fix our Wiis. I need your help, guys. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I feel for you, man. But our expertise doesn't really run to modding a console, let alone restoring it. While we allow questions about getting emulation working, this is well outside that.

Comment: I believe that this is *not* off-topic as per the meta posts, [What's the official stance on hacked/modded consoles?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/258/4797) and [How should we deal with direct questions on hardware modding?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/3877/4797) Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get bootmii to work you must first install it with letterbomb. To do this go into the letters section of your wii locate the letterbomb (it is red and has a bomb sticking out of it) when you open it select the bootmii installer (It should be under the homebrew channel) Next time you open bootmii from the home brew channel it should load properly and not get stuck on a black screen. Note the wii controller will stop working this is normal you can use the buttons on the wii console to navigate the options. After you settup bootmii the controllers will work again.

Also if you have started bootmii before installing it from letter bomb and you are stuck on a black screen it is safe to turn of your wii.

Comment: Thanks @Qwertie ϟ. You're exactly right. Now, if I run BootMii, do I just put nand.bin on my SD card and run BootMii recovery?

Comment: @Rhyknowscerious Are you trying to un mod your wii? Because bootmii is only for restoring your wii to the last backup made with it. not for unmodding it. I will try and find a way to unmod it and I will put it here.

Comment: @Rhyknowscerious Here are instructions on how to unmod your wii https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120321181501AA6dYaG. Note I have never done this and cant help you anymore. Hope it goes well :D

Comment: Thanks, @Qwertie ϟ. That guide sounds like the way to go but it states that there's a chance to brick the Wii. Before I do that, I want to make sure BootMii can restore a backup. Do you know if the BootMii recovery will reset any IOSs/cIOSs?

Comment: @Rhyknowscerious Bootmii should restore the wii to exactly how it was at the backup but this process involves removing bootmii so if something happens after bootmii is removed you won't be able to restore the backup. Why are you trying to unmod your wii anyway?